# Node.js - Mongodb - Mongoose / Can't pass Array string into $push feild

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

So im attempting to push a different index per array into a $push call to populate a mongodb server however Im having trouble with making the call specific to the array that I am attempting to access

There is an inital array that is set for IP addresses and Array names in the database that they need to be set to

```
//Team IP Info
var teamIps = [
    '8.8.8.8',
    '8.8.8.9',
    '8.8.8.8',
    '8.8.8.8',
    '8.8.8.8',
]
var boxNames = [
    'Linux1',
    'Linux2',
    'Windows1',
    'Windows2',
    '98',
]
```

This is the code for the $push call

```
for (let index = 0; index < teamIps.length; index++) {
    var hostIn = teamIps[index];
    const boxName = boxNames[index];
    const liTest = 'services.0.ICMP_Linux1'
    var db_base = 'services.0.ICMP_';
    var db_index = db_base.concat(boxName);
    console.log('Inital : ' + boxName)

    //This should work and makes life easier but I cant append the db_index string into the mongoose push call

    var result = await session.pingHost(hostIn, function (error, hostIn, sent, rcvd) {
        var ms = rcvd - sent;
        var db_base = 'services.0.ICMP_';
        var db_index = db_base.concat(boxName).toString();
        console.log(typeof db_index)
        if (error){
            var output = hostIn + ": " + error.toString()
            Team.findOneAndUpdate(
                { name: name }, 
                {$push: {db_index :{ timeStamp: epochTime , status: false , error: error.toString()} }},
                function(err,suc){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(hostIn + ' : ' + db_index + " : " + output)
                    }
                });
            // res.send({
            //     result: output
            // })
        }
        else{
            var output = hostIn + ": Alive (ms=" + ms + ")"
            Team.findOneAndUpdate(
                { name: name }, 
                {$push: {db_index :{ timeStamp: epochTime , status: true , speed: ms} }},
                function(err,suc){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }else{
                        console.log(hostIn + ' : ' + db_index + " : " + output)
                    }
                });
            // res.send({
            //     result: output
            // })
        }
    });
```

In this call

```
{$push: {db_index :{ timeStamp: epochTime , status: false , error: error.toString()}
```

I would like to be able to change the db_index to each in the array however it always defaults to the actual word db_index

I cant seem to figure out how to pass a string into this call without it failing

A call that works looks something like this

```
{$push: {'services.0.ICMP_Linux1':{ timeStamp: epochTime , status: false , error: error.toString()} }},
```

Everything works database side and when manually passed with this call it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use computed property names:

```
{$push: {[db_index] :{ timeStamp: epochTime , status: false , error: error.toString()} } }
```

Comment: Thank you this is the solution I search docs for hours and couldn't find it. Just brackets  [ ] -_-